# Multiple Plot query under a same caption with different labales problem

Tags: plot

I have 6 figures and I want to plot them under a same caption with different labels.
I have tried two codes for plotting but they are not working.

Codes:

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=30mm]{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/25_for.jpeg} \\
  \subfloat b)    \includegraphics[width=80mm]{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/28_for.jpeg} \\
     \subfloat c)   \includegraphics[width=80mm]{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/29_for.jpeg} \\
  \subfloat d)    \includegraphics[width=80mm]{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/31_for.jpeg} \\
     \subfloat e)    \includegraphics[width=80mm]{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/32_for.jpeg} \\
  \subfloat f)    \includegraphics[width=80mm]{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/ob_for.jpeg} \\
    \rule{35em}{0.3pt}
 \caption{Patterns of Wireless sensor networks with respect to the MetoSwiss Forecasts for $2007-09-30$}
    \label{fig: pattern30}
\end{figure}
```

and :

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=80mm]{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/25_for.jpeg}
  \includegraphics[width=80mm]{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/28_for.jpeg}
  \\
  \includegraphics[width=80mm]{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/29_for.jpeg}
   \includegraphics[width=80mm]{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/31_for.jpeg}
    \\
     \includegraphics[width=80mm]{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/32_for.jpeg} 
   \includegraphics[width=80mm]{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/ob_for.jpeg}
        \rule{35em}{0.3pt}
    \caption{Patterns of Wireless sensor networks with respect to the MetoSwiss Forecasts for $2007-09-30$}
    \label{fig: pattern29}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Closed, as it was just a format problem, as commented by the OP below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is with `subfig` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} %5 Remove demo in your file
\usepackage{subfig}
\graphicspath{{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
        \centering
        \subfloat[]{%
        \includegraphics[width=.48\textwidth]{{25_for}.jpg}
        \label{fig:sub1}
        }%
        \hfill
        \subfloat[]{%
        \includegraphics[width=.48\textwidth]{{28_for}.jpg}
        \label{fig:sub2}
        }\\
        \subfloat[]{%
        \includegraphics[width=.48\textwidth]{{29_for}.jpg}
        \label{fig:sub3}
        }%
        \hfill
        \subfloat[]{%
        \includegraphics[width=.48\textwidth]{{31_for}.jpg}
        \label{fig:sub4}
        }\\
        \subfloat[]{%
        \includegraphics[width=.48\textwidth]{{32_for}.jpg}
        \label{fig:sub5}
        }%
        \hfill
        \subfloat[]{%
        \includegraphics[width=.48\textwidth]{{ob_for}.jpg}
        \label{fig:sub6}
        }
        \caption{Patterns of Wireless sensor networks with respect to the MetoSwiss Forecasts for $2007-09-30$}
    \label{fig:pattern29}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As a side note, it is not good to use `underscore` in figure file name. If needed try replacing them with `hyphens` (-) like `25-for.jpeg`. As discovered by the Op, the problem was with the extension `.jpeg` instead of `.jpg`

Comment: The problem was with the format, it should be .jpg

Comment: @user1885733 Oh. I overlooked it as it was `demo` for us. :-) I only suspected that it has something to do with file name.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [`subcaption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/subcaption) and its `subfigure` environment for this.

Also, rather than specifying the complete directory path each time, you can simply use

```
\graphicspath{{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/}}
```

as detailed in the [`graphicx`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/graphicx) documentation.

If that directory only contains `.jpeg` files, then there's no need to use the extension on the images.

To get the images in the code below, remove the `demo` option from the `graphicx`, i.e, just `\usepackage{graphicx}`

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\graphicspath{{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{80mm}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{25_for.jpeg}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{80mm}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{28_for.jpeg}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \\
    \begin{subfigure}{80mm}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{29_for.jpeg}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{80mm}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{31_for.jpeg}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \\
    \begin{subfigure}{80mm}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{32_for.jpeg} 
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{80mm}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ob_for.jpeg}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \caption{Patterns of Wireless sensor networks with respect to the MetoSwiss Forecasts for $2007-09-30$}
    \label{fig:pattern29}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Again, no plots are presented

Comment: @user1885733 have you removed the `demo` option? can you update your question with more details of the output that you are getting- what error messages do you get?